# Possible to simulate screen raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a terrain with meshes. The terrain is simply a combination of meshes (like 64 of them). There is a render texture that serves as a heightmap and I sample the heightmap texture to determine vertex y.

[image]

How can I know the 3D position of where the mouse pointer intersect the mesh?

**Further explanation:**

1. The heightmap texture is maintained and manipulated on the GPU and it may be subject to change in every frame so the solution should run in every frame.
2. There is no collider for mesh.
3. It can be assumed that the meshes are in an exclusive layer.
4. It maybe possible to assume that the meshes are the only objects in the scene (Only acceptable if it can make a tremendous performance advantage).
5. If we see this as a rendering issue can we just decrease the shader's rendering queue number and hook a method on CPU to sample from the target depth buffer when this particular render queue is drawn and before other draw calls happen and then convert the combination of mouse position and depth to determine 3d position?

Comment: This will be hard to do without Mesh Collider.....

Comment: The problem is heightmap is updated every frame as it is affected by an erosion algorithm. And that rate of update makes having colliders impossible

Comment: With your erosion algorithm, do you know every point of your terrain?

Comment: @cjf93 Yes the height for every point in terrain is present in a texture.

Comment: i don't know if this is possible but you can create a edge collider on the base of the terrain, and know where your raycast is colliding.
With this point and the camera position you can know every point of the Raycast, and using your algorithm compute every point of this Raycast and see what is the highest point on your terrain.
The highest one will be your collision. Am i right? Is this possible?

Comment: @cjf93 It is possible and maybe is the way to go. The problem with this approach is that the heightmap RenderTexture is on the GPU and in order to do a custom algorithm like this I have to read pixels from it and store them in an array and then it would be possible to implement the algorithm you proposed. Nevertheless optimizing this process by reading pixels in chunks may solve the performance issue,